# Inner Join in hql and how to iterate

Tags: hibernate, join, iterator, hql, one-to-one

i need some help i have new to hibernate i have joined three tables using inner joins which all are having one to one mapping i am getting the result in list but, how to iterate in that list. i have tried using iterator but nothing helps please help me here is the code snippet.

```
@Entity
public class Laptop {
@Id
private int lid;
private String lname;
//getters and setter

@Entity
public class Validity{

@Id
private int lid;
private String validitydate;
//getters and setter
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
private int lid;
private int rollno;
private String name;
private int marks;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="lid")
private Laptop laptop;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="lid")
private Validity validity;
//getters and setters
```

Query that i am firing

```
  String hql = "Select s from Student s inner join s.laptop left join 
   s.validity where s.lid = 1 and s.marks = 45";


    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

    List<Object[]> list = query.list();

    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    Object[] obj = list.toArray();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Object ob = (Object)it.next();
        Student s = (Student)ob;
        System.out.println("Student id is "+s.getLid());
        Laptop l = (Laptop)ob; // gives me error here cannot cast laptop to 
        student
        System.out.println("laptop id is "+l.getLid());
        System.out.println("laptop name is "+l.getLname());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is

```
Select s from Student s where ...
```

So it selects instances of Student.

So the result is a `List<Student>`, not a `List<Object[]>`.

Use the right type, and use typed queries:

```
Query<Student> query = session.createQuery(hql, Student.class);
List<Student> list = query.list();
for (Student student : list) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: but i want details from Laptop class as well as Validity Class

Comment: Then it's a good thing that Student has a laptop and a validity fields. And you can thuse use student.getLaptop() to get the laptop of the student. You don't think to understand the principle of classes and objects. Given your question and the code you posted, I think it's way too early for you to use Hibernate. Learn the basics of Java and OO first. For example, you should know that an object can't be both a Student and a Laptop at the same time, and yet that's what your code is assuming.

Comment: Thank for ur help this is what i did..to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    Object[] obj = list.toArray();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Object ob = (Object)it.next();
        Student s = (Student)ob;
        System.out.println("Student id is "+s.getLid());
        Laptop l = s.getLaptop();
        System.out.println("laptop id is "+l.getLid());
        System.out.println("laptop name is "+l.getLname());
        Validity v = s.getValidity();
        System.out.println("Validity id is "+v.getLid());
        System.out.println("Validity Date is "+v.getValiditydate());

    }
```